# flyway for Linux and Windows

Tags: flyway

Can I manage the same database schame using both the linux and windows versions?  I'm curious if metadata added in schwma_version (e.g. db/v_10_1__test.sql) from linux will be recognized when I run flyway from Windows, which would have expected "db\v_10_1_test.sql".

Comment: I think your question is "can I use [Flyway](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/) to synchronize my database schema between Windows and Linux?"  Q: What database are you using?  The same DB on each platform?  Q: Does your schema use any vendor-specific extensions, datatypes, or stored procedures?

Comment: It's one database. But I will have different teams updating the same database from different platforms (e.g. developers use Windows and DBAs use Linux).  That's why I want to make sure that metadata inserted using a Windows tool is recognized by a Linux tool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The code is identical and locations are normalized to a common format before storing them in the metadata table.

Comment: Great.  Just to confirm, everything is normalized to the Linux/Unix format. Correct?  And the metadata will look identical whether I use mvn or commandline-tool to migrate the same DDL script?

Comment: Everything is normalized to the java classpath format: my/directory/tree/file.extension. No difference between api, ant, mvn and cmd-line.